# Migration from StatelessKnowledgeSession to StatelessKieSession

Tags: drools, kie

I'm looking to migrate from the older Knowledge Api to Kie Api on Drools 6, and stop using obsolete classes. In the current code, we have POJO for DroolFact which we pass to `session.execute` for processing.

Since this is the older 5.x code, it uses `StatelessKnowledgeSession`; and I tried replacing with `KieSession`. However, the newer `KieSession` doesn't take Object as parameter for the `execute()` method but `Command<T>` instead.

Looking at Drools 6 examples, the facts class is still a simple POJO which doesn't implement any specific interface. Though, the examples I saw are also using `fireAllRules()` rather than execute. How should I update existing code to use Kie Api in this case?

Edit:  I just found out after posting that `StatelessKieSession` **does** have same method, I was using base `KieSession` class. So that has resolved my compilation error, but I'm leaving the question up in case there are any other upgrade issues to be aware of.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not going to Drools 7? I did a migration of several million rules from 5.0.1 to 7.12 and it is totally do-able. A 'command' is simply like: `cmds.add( kieCommands.newInsert( new Person( "jon", 102 ) ) );`, so you can put your Objects into working memory that way.

Comment: This is aiming for Drools 7, I'm just migrating the code while using 6 library since it still contains the deprecated classes.

Comment: Makes sense. My code in particular was using stateful sessions so it was pretty much a painless migration, but a command is just a wrapper around an insert statement so it should be equally simple.